# Is there a NuGet package for Microsoft.Xrm.Client?

Tags: nuget, dynamics-crm, nuget-package, dynamics-crm-online

Is there a NuGet package for Microsoft.Xrm.Client for Dynamics 2013 and 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,
it's inside this official nuget package:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions/